# Multiple layers android Animation

Tags: android, animation, view, android-framelayout

I am working on an android application that requires multiple views which will overlap each other in one main view (FramLayout).  Each of those 3 views will be the same size and have different kinds of animations.  As far as the design, what would be the best approach?  I would prefere to do this programmatically.  Is there an example of different views being overlapped with animations?

Comment: Also how would I go on doing this programmatically? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I had was have 3 views with view inflators wihtin the framelayout, Have the main animations with a surface view in the front then have less animations with the othe views behind them. This will allow you to easily update one of the previous layers :)